# Having issue printing out data i want to show

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

i was modifying a program that i was writing to make it so that it wont continue on unless they put in a  input that matches a word thats stored in a  list. however after i did that, it would not let me print out the data i have, here is the code

```
while True:


        dept = input('what department are you  in right now: ')
        dept = dept.upper()
        if dept not in department_storage:
            print("not approriate response")
            continue
        else:
            break
        if dept in department_storage:
            department_url = requests.get(f"https://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id={dept}")
            specific_major =department_url.json()
            keep_keys = ["course_id"]
            courses = [{k: json_dict[k] for k in keep_keys}
                      for json_dict in specific_major]


        #return courses,dept
            print(courses)
```

im trying to print out the courses variable, however when i try and run the function
it doesn't show the print output, and it doesn't show any errors when i run it so im lost on what i did wrong and how to fix it . i was wondering if i could ask the kind stack overflow community for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be getting the output for multiple reasons: -

1. Did you enter an input? the interpreter may be waiting for a user input which has not been entered yet.
2. Maybe the `dept not in department_storage` is breaking the loop if its true. `break` gets you out of the loop.
3. `courses` is a null object, probably because the result you are getting has empty objects.

You can add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace();` at various points in your code and write the variable names in the debugger to see the values. That will aid you in the investigation.

As per the requirement, my suggestion is the following code: -

```py
while True:
    dept = input('what department are you in right now: (type exit to quit)')
    dept = dept.upper()
    if dept == 'EXIT':
        break
    if dept not in department_storage:
        print("this department does not exist, enter correct department")
    else:
        try:
            department_url = requests.get(f"https://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id={dept}")
            specific_major =department_url.json()
            keep_keys = ["course_id"]
            courses = [{k: json_dict[k] for k in keep_keys}
                      for json_dict in specific_major]
            print(courses)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: the courses object usually had something in it if the input is valid, it was showing before i modified my code. for the break, should i add the break at the end of the while loop?

Comment: it depends what you are trying to do. If the courses objects cannot be empty, you should try hitting the api externally to confirm it isnt empty. if the code you have written reflects what you want to achieve, then its correct. You should write your `break` in the case where you want your loop to stop. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to make it so that it would keep asking until the user inputs a valid input thats in the department_storage list i have, then if they want to not input anymore then break out of the loop. i was able to get courses to print but the problem i face now is that im in a infinite loop and i want to make it so that if they type a certain input they can break out. @Pranav Sharma

Comment: If this helped you, do mark the answer as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `break` command forces to exit the while loop and stop taking inputs.

Try:

```
if dept in department_storage:
    ...
# if dept not in department_storage
else:
    ...
```

Comment: i apologize, im confused on the solution, would you like me to add the break as the last thing?

Comment: Sorry, I'm suggesting that if you are only conditioning on one variable, `dept` here, one if-elif-else block should do the trick.